# jqgrid pagination with postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jqgrid

Until now I was using jqgrid with mysql and php. My code is adapted to the examples given in the jqGrid Demos site.
The data provided by the javascript part are:

- page =1
- rows =8
- sord=asc

  ```
  $page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
  $limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid 
  $sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort 
  $sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction 
  if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; // connect to the database    
  $connection = mysql_connect($serveur,$user,$password);
  $db = mysql_select_db($bdd, $connection); 
  mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Preferences WHERE (Id_Membre ='$idm')";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$connection); 
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
  $count = $row['count']; 
  if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
      $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
  }
  else { 
      $total_pages = 0; 
  } 

  if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages; 

  $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1) 
  if ($start<0) $start = 0;
  $query = "select * from Preferences where (Id_Membre ='$idm') order by $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
  ```

The last query returns 4 rows.

This is the same code adapted for Postgresql. With the same data, this code return nothing !

```
    $page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
    $limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid 
    $sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort 
    $sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction 
    if (!$sidx) $sidx =1; // connect to the database    
    $connection = pg_connect($con);

    pg_query($connection,"set names 'utf8'");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM preference WHERE (id_membre ='$idm')";
    $result = pg_query($connection,$query); 
    $row = pg_fetch_array($result); 
    $count = $row['count']; 
    if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
        $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
    }
    else { 
        $total_pages = 0; 
    } 

    if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages; 

    $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1) 
    if ($start<0) $start = 0;  
    $query = "select * from preference where (id_membre ='$idm') order by $sidx $sord  LIMIT $start OFFSET $limit";
    $result = pg_query($connection,$query);
```

Any ideas ?
I thought that limit 0,8 becomed limit 0 offset 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**limit 0,8** in mysql means **limit 8 offset 0** in postgres.

```
$query = "select * from preference where (id_membre ='$idm') 
    order by $sidx $sord LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start";
```

Comment: limit $a,$b means limit $b offset $a. Some stackoverflow users give the contrary !